# getting error for mockito anyListOf(String.class)

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

I am trying to stub my method using mockito `when(..).thenReturn(..)` but I am getting error. Please let me know what wrong I am doing here ...

Here is my method call ...

```
public List<Subscriber> getSubscribers(SubscriberDetailRequestRoot subscriberDetailRequestRoot, List<String> accIds) {....}
```

and I am stubbing like below in my test class ...

```
when(subscriberComponent.getSubscribers(any(SubscriberDetailRequestRoot.class),anyListOf(String.class))).thenReturn(listSubscriber);
```

and I am getting below error ...

```
    org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InvalidUseOfMatchersException: 
Misplaced argument matcher detected here:
-> at SubscriberComponentTest.testGetSubscribers(SubscriberComponentTest.java:68)
You cannot use argument matchers outside of verification or stubbing.
Examples of correct usage of argument matchers:
when(mock.get(anyInt())).thenReturn(null);
doThrow(new RuntimeException()).when(mock).someVoidMethod(anyObject());
verify(mock).someMethod(contains("foo"))
Also, this error might show up because you use argument matchers with methods that cannot be mocked.
Following methods *cannot* be stubbed/verified: final/private/equals()/hashCode().
Mocking methods declared on non-public parent classes is not supported.
```

#### Question 2.

how to use `anyListOf(String.class)` for `readAccount(String name, List<String> accIds)`
whenever I try

```
when(subscriberComponent.readAccount(anyString(),anyListOf(String.class)).thenRetur(..);

subscriberComponent.readAccount(anyString(),anyListOf(String.class)) ;
```

I am getting errors. Please explain me how to use `anyListOf(<T>)` method of mockito or let me know how to pass a generic list of strings to `readAccount()` . Thanks

### Edited

Here is the method i am trying to test 'Question 2`

```
 public List<Subscriber> readAccount(String name, List<String> accIds) {
    List<Subscriber> lstSubscriber = new ArrayList<Subscriber>();

    for (String accId : accIds) {
        Subscriber sub = accountReader.readAccount(name, accId, Subscriber.class);
        if (sub.getProduct()!=null)
            lstSubscriber.add(sub);
    }

    return lstSubscriber;

}
```

I have Mocked `AccountReader` and inject to `SubscriberComponent` with `@InjectMocks`

```
@Mock
private AccountReader accountReader ;

@InjectMocks
private SubscriberComponent subscriberComponent;

@Test
public void readAccountCallsAccountReaderForEachIds() throws Exception {

// I have to define accIds here to call my method. but I want the generic way to call my method below 

List<String> accIds = new ArrayList<String>();
    accIds.add("12333441");
    accIds.add("12333442");
    accIds.add("12333443");
    String name = "NAME" ;


//setup
  when(accountReader.readAccount(anyString(),anyString(),eq(Subscriber.class))).thenReturn(subscriber);
    when(subscriber.getPlan()).thenReturn(plan);
    //execute
    //subscriberComponent.readAccount(name,accIds); --- HERE I want to call something like 

  subscriberComponent.readAccount(anyString(),anyListOf(String.class));

    //verify
    assertEquals(3,subscriberComponent.readAccount(name,accIds).size() );
    verify(accountReader, times(3)).readAccount(anyString(),anyString(), eq(Subscriber.class));

}
```

Comment: Answer 1: `subscriberComponent` is not a mock, so you can't mock the method. Answer 2: Post `readAccount` definition please

Comment: Thanks for quick response... i have added `readAccount` definition above, please check. Thanks.